# Changing a css class from javascript

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I want to set an element's `height` to `window.innerheight` but I have to do it in CSS because somehow I don't have access to that element to use javascript to change it's style.
Is there a way to do that? like changing a CSS class in javascript?

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('root').style.setProperty('--view-height', window.innerHeight +'px');
```

and in CSS:

```
.menu {
    height: var(--view-height) !important;
}
```

and  it works but [CSS Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) is not supported in older browsers so I can't use that, but I want something similar.

**EDIT:
There is many answer yet they all use javascript, i said i CAN NOT USE js to set the element style! i want to do it only by css class style**

Comment: Maybe a polyfill would help you with the older Browser issue?

Comment: With this you can add a classname and in your CSS set styles to that new classname. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp

Comment: how to i set style to window.innerheight in css? !!

Answer (score 0):

Set `height` in javascript instead use `variables`

```
document.getElementById('root').style.height=window.innerHeight +'px';
```

See example:

```js
 document.getElementById('root').style.height=window.innerHeight +'px';
```

```css
#root{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

**To your edit no use js use `height:100vh;` :**

```css
#root{
height:100vh;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: hey.. is this what you looking for?

Comment: see my edit please using css and not js

Comment: no 100 vh has a problem in IOS devices:

Comment: u must use js maybe use js only if you in mobile size sceen

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can use:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('MyClass');
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('MyOtherClass');
```

Although, for accomplishing your specific case, I'd go with [לבני מלכה](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9140740/%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94)'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use proper CSS instead:

`window.innerHeight +'px'` results in the same height as using `100vh`. The unit `vh` means "viewport height" and `100vh` is the full height of the inner window.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

Comment: https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html

Comment: 100 vh has a problem in IOS devices

Comment: @MahboobehMohammadi Oh, OK. I just looked at https://caniuse.com/#search=vh and was satisfied by the green indicator…

Answer (score 0):

using `vh` unit is the proper way to do this.. (although Mahboobeh Mohammadi said that it isn't compatible with ios)
 `height: 100vh;` is the full height of the view..

Answer (score -1):

For Normal Js

```
function addClassById (_id,_class) {
  document.getElementById(_id).classList.add(_class);
}

function removeClassById (_id,_class) {
  document.getElementById(_id).classList.remove(_class);
}

addClassById("root","newClass")
```

I advise to you use JQUERY it s very easy to use. 
Put this cdn link on your head tag then use it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

//This is for change css
$("#root").css({
"background-color": "yellow", 
"font-size": "200%"
});



 // This is how to add class
$("#root").addClass('newClass');





// This is how to remove class
 $("#root").removeClass('newClass')
```

I hope it help you.